# Automation reporting tool for parallel test runs

Tags: java, reporting, junit

I am looking for a reporting tool that I can use to provide an outline for parallel tests that I am running using maven, junit, cucumber. Preferably if this could be as simple as a dependency/plugin that I would need to add to the project that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Allure Test Report](http://allure.qatools.ru/). It supports different languages. Reports can be received in various formats, and it's free.

> Allure is based on standard xUnit results output but adds some supplementary data. Any report is generated in two steps. During test execution (first step), a small library called adapter attached to the testing framework saves information about executed tests to XML files. We already provide adapters for popular Java, PHP, Ruby, Python, Scala and C# test frameworks.
>
> During report generation (second step), the XML files are transformed to a HTML report. This can be done with a command line tool, a plugin for CI or a build tool. See examples and documentation for more details